# Textures show black when using GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR in emscripten

Tags: opengl-es, webgl, emscripten

I have a small program that just draws a full screen quad with a texture.

This program works fine when I run it on Windows.

However it seems to fail when compiling to WebGL2 (GLES3) using Emscripten. It just shows a black quad.

I have figured out that the problem happens only when I enable mipmapping.

```cpp
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
```

This is the code that initializes the texture:

```cpp
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glGenTextures(1, &tex);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
struct Color { u8 r, g, b; };
const Color pixels[] = {
    {255, 0, 0}, {0, 255, 0},
    {0, 0, 255}, {255, 255, 0}
};
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_SRGB8, 2, 2, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
//glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
//glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
//glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

EDIT:

I have found that, if instead of calling `glGenerateMipmap`, I specify the mip levels manually, it works!

```cpp
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_SRGB8, 2, 2, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, GL_SRGB8, 1, 1, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
```

Repo with the full code: https://github.com/tuket/emscripten_problem_with_mipmap_textures

EDIT2:

Another interesting finding: if instead of using a 3-channel texture, I use a 4-channel texture, it works!

```cpp
struct Color { u8 r, g, b, a; };
const Color pixels[] = {
    {255, 0, 0, 255}, {0, 255, 0, 255},
    {0, 0, 255, 255}, {255, 255, 0, 255}
};
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_SRGB8_ALPHA8, 2, 2, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

Comment: I believe that calling `glGenerateMipmap` on anything but a linear RGBA texture results in undefined behavior and/or an invalid operation.

Comment: In WebGL that is.

Comment: @LJᛃ In WebGL 2.0 it should behave the same as in OpenGL ES 3.0. There are no limitations in the specs: [OpenGL ES 3.0 Specifications](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/index_es.php#specs3), [WebGL 2.0 Specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/2.0/)

Comment: @Rabbid76 you're right, if I see it correctly in the [v8 source](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/main/gpu/command_buffer/service/texture_manager.cc#947) the texture needs to be filterable **and** color renderable though, the latter might be the issue here.

Comment: @LJᛃ Hm, RGB doesn't have to be color renderable (RGBA does)

Comment: Wow, I would have never guessed! I believe there should be an error/warning message

Comment: @Rabbid76 Hold on, according to the spec RGB8 is both color-renderable and texture-filterable. SRGB8_ALPHA isn't color renderable. But it doesn't seem to work in any of the two. Weird... https://imgur.com/a/2sfhN7E

Comment: You should see an `invalid operation` (or something alike) error in the browser console during execution.

Comment: @LJᛃ True, now I see it! And for some reason, now it seems to be working for RGB8... I guess didn't recompile my code correctly or something. Thanks!